# Converting a string to a decimal value in an SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, derived

I have a flat file that I am importing into SQL Server 2008 using an SSIS package.

The file contains a field with a number, followed by a column with a negative sign when the preceding column value is negative.

For instance:

```
Price    Sign
-----    -----
9212.00 
  29.01    -
 268.00    -
 453.02
```

I want to load this value into a decimal column on a table.

In order to accomplish this, I am creating a derived column in my Data Flow Task.  The expression for the derived column is `[Sign] + [Price]`.  I have (using the Advanced Editor) defined the derived column as type decimal `[DT_DECIMAL]`.

Then I'm simply loading the data (along with the derived column) into my table.

Does this sound like a good way to handle this situation?  Is there another method that I should consider instead?  Any 'gotchas' with using this method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems to be the best option.  The default data type for each column from the flat file is  string.  So, your `[Sign] + [Price]` expression is doing string concatenation.  And, the data is implicitly converted to a decimal value when moved to your output column.

One change that would improve readability is to explicitly cast the string value to a decimal.  You can change your expression in the Derived Column component to this:

```
(DT_DECIMAL, scale)[Sign] + [Price]
```

where `scale` is a number that will match the data type for your output column.

With this change, the output from your Derived Column component will be the decimal data type.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will not work...

1. You need to convert `Sign` to string data type and `Price` to numeric.
2. Then compare if `Sign` is `"-"`, if is, multiple from `-1`.

Derived Column Code Example:

```
(DT_WSTR, 1) [Sign]=="-"?  [Price]*-1 :  [Price]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Can you explain why my approach above will not work?  Based upon what I'm seeing, it did appear to work.

Comment: For example (sorry, can't post images): <code> Derived Column Name Derived Column Expression Data Type ------------------- -------------- ---------- --------- Final_Price <add as new> [sign]+[price] decimal[DT_DECI </code> So: Price = 232.43 Sign= - becomes -232.43 and when I load into my database this value goes into the column on the table defined as decimal(10,2) as -232.43. Just want to make sure I understand the benefits of the second approach over the first. Thanks again.

Comment: I see, but still don't know why this works, because `Sign` data type must be string, then you want sum `Sign` string and `Price` decimal this should not work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7527 What data types are before derived columns of `Sign` and `Price`.